# Php utf8 / unicode encoding

Tags: php, json, unicode, utf-8, encode

I have a strings like

```
$string1 = 'love is all mine ';
$string2 = 'Sarah is good girl⭐';
$string3 = 'हिन्दी ya ⭐';
$string4 = 'hái 还/還 ("still"), yǐjīng 已经 ';
```

i want to encode them in a harmless encoded strings like

`Api Hatal\u0131d\u0131r. L\u00fctfen kontrol ederek tekrar deneyiniz`

in which no special charactor and utf8 character so that i can use it in javascript. I have tried `utf8_encode()` and `mb_convert_encoding( $string4 , 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');`. `utf8_encode()` is simply not working as it is giving error in javasciprt (because i want to create json response and to use it in my code). and `mb_convert_encoding( $string4 , 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');` is converting whole string into other Chinese characters.

Comment: i tried "json_encode(string)" and it just worked.

Comment: Your code is also valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **iconv** for converting

```
iconv('utf-8', 'utf-8//IGNORE',$str);
```

and change utf-8 encoding to anything you want.
first parameter is your current text encoding and second one is which encoding you want to convert it to.function doc is ...

```
string iconv ( string $input_charset, string $output_charset, string $str )
```

Comment: will it make utf8 charactors as `\u0131d\u0131` ?